# how to set bold and italics when using the outlook interop from C#

Tags: c#, interop, outlook

I have the following C# code to launch an outlook window.  The one think i want to add it to have certain part of the text bold and italics.  how would i do that through this API?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oRecip;

oMsg.Subject = "Autogenerated Daily Report for: " + DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString("MMM dd");
oMsg.Body = message;

oRecip = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)oMsg.Recipients.Add("test@test.com");
oRecip.Resolve();

oMsg.Display(true);

oRecip = null;
oMsg = null;
oApp = null;
```

Comment: I've not tried this before, but have you tired using HTML message body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your message HTML, and use HTML tags as necessary to get the formatting you want.

Example:

```
.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "<html><body><h2>The body of this message will appear in HTML." + 
            "</h2>Type the Message text here.</body></html>";
```